# Disable specific C++ lines and #includes when building on another system

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, build, makefile

I'm using the Google glog logging system in my project.  Specifically, I'm using the following types of statements at various places in my code:

```
#include <glog/logging.h>
CHECK_EQ(foo,bar) << "Generic error message";
LOG(ERROR) << "Generic error message";
LOG(FATAL) << "Generic error message";
```

This logging system is important in helping me to stage and verify my code. However, sometimes I farm out production runs of my code to a larger server.  This large production server doesn't have the logging system. (I've tried to build the logging system on this production server, but have run into problems.)

So, working on the assumption that I *cannot* use the logging system on the production server, how can I configure things so that the logging commands are inactive on the server?

---

Attempting to solve this problem myself before asking on SO, I tried the following...

In an existing header file named "globals.h" I defined:

```
#ifdef NOGLOG
    #define MYLOG(i,m) std::cerr << #i << ": " << m
#else
    #include <glog/logging.h>
    #define MYLOG(i,m) LOG(i) << m
#endif
```

Then, I can replace code like `LOG(ERROR) << "ab" << x << "cd"` with `MYLOG(ERROR,"ab" << x << "cd")`.  Then, when I build with a command like `make all CUSTOM="-DNOGLOG"`, where my gcc compile statements are set up with a variable named `$(CUSTOM)`, the glog statements will not get compiled, but instead simple `std::cerr` statements will get compiled.

I ran into two problems with this approach: (1) I could not figure out how to get the Eclipse IDE to insert `$(CUSTOM)` into the gcc compile statements in the makefile that Eclipse generates; and (2) putting the `#include <glog/logging.h>` statement inside the `#else` body caused lots of error messages like the one below.

```
In file included from /usr/include/errno.h:36,
                 from /usr/local/include/glog/logging.h:39,
                 from ../globals.h:23,
                 from ../COMPASS.h:11,
                 from ../COMPASS.cpp:13:
/usr/include/bits/errno.h: In function 'int* __errno_location()':
/usr/include/bits/errno.h:43: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
```

**Note:** For the time being, I just commented-out the `CHECK_EQ` calls, with the thinking that once I figure out how to fix this problem with respect to the `LOG` calls, I should be able to easily extend the solution to the `CHECK_EQ` calls.

Comment: Veeery long question for a pretty simple thing. Did you have a look at your project's properties 'C++ General -> Paths and Symbols' #Symbols Tab? There are various other approaches available with Eclipse CDT Toolchains.

Comment: Also: /usr/include/bits/errno.h - what a hack of an compile environment.

Comment: @g-makulik Thanks, I will look into that.  I've never messed with any of the Eclipse CDT Toolchains.  So this is all new to me.

Comment: @DieterLücking I think that's due to the glog library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your compilation problem,

`message << x << y` is not valid.

you may use something like:

```
// mystream.h

// class MyStreamImpl; // forward declaration for pimpl idiom if necessary

class MyStream
{
public:
    MyStream(int level);
    ~MyStream();

    MyStream& operator << (const char*);
    MyStream& operator << (int);
    // some other needed base type.
private:
    int level;
    // std::unique_ptr<MyStreamImpl> m_impl; // for pimpl idiom if necessary
};

MyStream MYLOG(int level) { return MyStream(level); }


// mylog.cpp


#ifdef NOGLOG
#include <iostream>

// implementation of all methods without glog

MyStream& MyStream::operator << (const char* message)
{
    std::cerr << message;
    return *this;
}

// other forwards to std::cerr

#else // NOGLOG

#include <glog/logging.h>

// implementation of all methods with glog

MyStream& MyStream::operator << (const char* message)
{
    Log(level) << message;
    return *this;
}

// other forwards to LOG()

#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful solution.  Question, though... why is `message << x << y` invalid?  It works for me.

Comment: true, is is not invalid, but misleading as `operator << (const char*, int)` doesn't exist. `stream << message << x << y` is seen as `(((stream << message) << x) << y)` where your notation suggests `stream << (message << x << y)` (which is incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

I accepted Jarod42's answer, but I wanted to add my own answer here, which I ultimately will probably use.  I think Jarod42's is probably more elegant and *better*, but my hack solution here is easy to implement.

---

I discovered that rather than try to add a variable to the CXXFLAGS in the compile step which I can then define to represent whether to use the glog system, it's easier to simply create another build configuration in Eclipse based on the existing `release` configuration.  In this new configuration, call it `release_noglog`, I can then go to Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Preprocessor, and add `NOGLOG` as a "defined symbol".  This way, building in `release` will *not* add `NOGLOG` to the compile statements, but building in `release_noglog` *will*.

Then, I can simply use the following macro definitions:

```
#ifdef NOGLOG
    #define MYLOG(i,m) std::cerr << #i << ": " << m
    #define MYCHECK_EQ(i,j,m) CHECK_EQ(i,j) << m
#else
    #define MYLOG(i,m) LOG(i) << m
    #define MYCHECK_EQ(i,j,m) std::cerr << #i << " != " << #j << ": " << m
#endif
```

And, I will *not* make `#include <glog/logging.h>` dependent on whether `NOGLOG` is defined, because the unresolved inclusions will not prevent compilation. (At least, not on the particular system in question.)

Comment: I would suggest to remove `m` parameter each time (and so `<< m`). So you can use `MYLOG` as `LOG`.